# Working with auto complete fields in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have added auto-complete field in my rails app to select the users for sending email notification. The auto complete field is working fine, but the problem is the "Submit and cancel button" are deactivated after selecting the email id of the user form the auto-complete list. And i am able to add only one email-id, but not multiple email-id.
I have used autocomplete-rails.js file as wel.

Can anyone suggest the solution for this problem ?

Comment: which gem or plugin you are using for autocomplete?

Comment: i used gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', Its working now. I changed the CSS property of the <div> in which the auto-complete field was included. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

You mean, you click, but nothing happens?

Check your validations. In some cases the html attr. required, blocks you from creating new records.

Comment: Its working now. I changed the CSS property of the <div> in which the auto-complete field was included. 
Thank you for the response